# Can Android OS prevent the calls to system service APIs from being fooled?

Tags: android, security, android-security

Android Application Framework provides a whole bunch of system services, such as PackageManagerService, ActivityManagerSerive. Most of the services are in the System Server process. The framework also provides a whole bunch of APIs to apps in the form of a set of proxy classes, such that when an app invokes proxy.API_foo(), the invocation will be handled, through the Binder mechanism, as a Remote Procedural Call by one of the system services.

My question is that, since all the proxy classes are in the memory address space of the app process, isn't is vulnerable to attacks by a hacked app? E.g., I can overwrite the "this" pointer of a proxy class of interest, such that "this" points to an arbitrary virtual function table.

Does the system provide any write-protection for those proxy class objects, so that they cannot be manipulated?

You may be wondering why I asked this silly question. I am considering such scenario: assuming an app is well protected against reverse engineering, but by adding code that manipulates the memory storing the proxy classes, I can still hack the high-value app (say a banking app, a health care app) somehow by returning fake values when system service APIs are called.

I found this but don't quite get it:
http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-replacing-system-classes.html

I also found a paper:
http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1575/paper_10.pdf

But the hacking requires the root privilege. Is that really necessary?

Links about System Services:

http://opensourceforu.com/2013/12/birds-eye-view-android-system-services/

https://www.slideshare.net/marakana/android-services-black-magic-by-aleksandar-gargenta

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/practical-android-phone-forensics/#gref

Comment: Your proposed virtual function table would have to point to locations within the app's own address space, not that of the `system_server` process. All framework classes are in copy-on-write memory pages, so the proposed virtual function table itself would only be in the app's process; any other processes forked from the zygote would be unaffected.

Comment: But at least the crafted app itself can affect itself, right? You may be wondering why I asked this silly question. I am considering such scenario: assuming an app is well protected against reverse engineering for copyright protection, but by manipulating the proxy classes, I can still reverse-engineer the high-value app (say a banking app, a health care app) and return fake values when system service APIs are called.

Comment: "But at least the crafted app itself can affect itself, right?" -- sure. "and return fake values when system service APIs are called" -- most likely, you can return "fake values" from any framework class, once you have the technique in place of replacing the framework class in your process. I have assumed that's how things like Xposed work. This does not mean that you can "reverse engineer" the app, at least in terms of how I would use that term, but you can certainly cause it to misbehave or identify certain things about its implementation.

Comment: @CommonsWare Does the Android operating system provide any protection against such manipulation? From what I can understand, since the proxy class is in the memory address space of the app process, there is really nothing that can stop the malicious code to overwrite the memory storing the proxy class code or the "this" field in the proxy object.

Comment: "Does the Android operating system provide any protection against such manipulation?" -- not that I am aware of. It certainly didn't used to, as I recall a specific case of Facebook hacking framework classes on the fly in their app. Android's security is focused on malware and remote attacks, more so than apps attacking themselves.